# For performance, what's the limit to how many levels up I can send data (via child to parent component)?

Tags: reactjs

There are several instances in my application that force me to break down certain pieces of my code into smaller components (UI improvements due to each component having its own state).

I will send a function bound to the parent component down to the child and when the new data is entered or changed in the child component, I send it to parent. Sometimes, I go 2 levels deep and have to send data from a child's child all the way to the parent when a change occurs.

Is there a limit to how many levels I can go before performance becomes an issue?

Comment: I suppose there is not any such performance issue when you pass props to multi level component, but when those props value changes in root component then whole tree rerender instead of that particular node which suppose to rerender.

Comment: But you can negate the rendering with `shouldComponentUpdate()` if certain criteria are not met..

Comment: yes, that the right solution but when it comes to code maintenance and a complex app and deep down component tree structure it will be very difficult to maintain, so its better to use redux and get your props into the required component.

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal Thanks for your answer. I agree with you.